# Reload window without closing Fancy Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reload

I have a fancybox with a form and an Ajax post behind it:

```
 var form = $("#myform");
 var data = form.serialize();
 var url = form.attr("action");
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: url,
     data: data,
 }).done(function() {
     location.reload();
     window.location.reload(true);
 }).fail(function() {}).error(function(httpObj, textStatus) {
     setTimeout(function() {
         $("#user_email").focus();
     }, 100);
     $("#quickSigninError").fadeIn();
     $("#loadingSpinnerPopup").fadeOut();
     $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", false);
     $("#submitBtnCurrent").prop("disabled", false);
     $("#cancelBtn").prop("disabled", false);
 });
```

The fancybox works great submits the form and reloads the fancybox when Ajax.done() occurs.

**The problem:**
I can reload the Fancybox with ease but now my question is how do I reload the original window that's behind the Fancybox without closing the Fancybox.

To emphasize the situation, please note the following screenshot:
[image]

Kind regards and thanks for anyone that can help me! :)

**EDIT1:** Goal is not to get the Fancybox closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant reload the website, that will reload your page ( including the fancybox. )

1. create an ajax call that will give you the page content
2. create another ajax and change the content of the parent

something to keep in mind, 
you better change all the content of a (div class="content")
and attach the fancybox to any object not inside the content div because it will be changed.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: data,
 }).done(function() {
    location.reload();
    // ajax to fetch div content //
    $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
      $( ".content" ).html( data );
      alert( "Load was performed." );
    });
 }).fail(function() {}).error(function(httpObj, textStatus) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#user_email").focus();
 }, 100);
    $("#quickSigninError").fadeIn();
    $("#loadingSpinnerPopup").fadeOut();
    $("#submitBtn").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#submitBtnCurrent").prop("disabled", false);
    $("#cancelBtn").prop("disabled", false);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and code example it's clear now what I have to do.

Answer (score -1):

Inside iframe use javascript:

```
parent.location.reload();
//or
parent.location.href = 'http://google.com'
```

Note, that iframe should contain code from same origin (the same domain, and the same protocol).

Comment: I tried parent.location.reload(); but it closes the fancybox.

Comment: Cause you don't understand what reload does.

When you run reload, you ask javascript to reload whole window. Window contains fancybox, but browser doesn't know that it has to open fancybox after reload. Do you understand? You can achieve that only by using separate browser window (as a popup), or modify DOM of parent by javascript. Decide what do you want to choose.